# How to run a single test under FunSuite in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, junit, scalatest

I'm running unit tests extending org.scalatest.FunSuite using the ScalaJUnit Test (or plain JUnit Test) runner in Eclipse Kepler.  When I select a single test to run in the JUnit pane, it runs, but then all the other tests run as well, under a heading designated "Unrooted Tests".

Is there a way to get just the single test I want to run?  I hate having to comment-out all the other tests just to simplify the output and save time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is possible when using the scalatest plugin for Eclipse (see this page: http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_eclipse ) and version 2.0 or later of ScalaTest itself.  In my case I had already found and installed the plugin, but I needed to upgrade the version of ScalaTest.

I performed the upgrade by changing the scalatest line in build.sbt, then asking SBT to regenerate the Eclipse project.  I hope there was a simpler way.

Comment: I was able to run a single test using the scalatest plugin for Eclipse. What I'm still missing is the ability to debug a single test.

Comment: So no way to do it in SBT?

Comment: Running a test in SBT is not exactly an answer to my question of how to run tests in Eclipse. However, if you're interested in running a single test under SBT, I suggest you start with the docs for the `testOnly` command, here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Running.html